# Is this a valid use of "when"?

Tags: grammar, subordinate-clauses, when

I want to make sure that this is a correct and natural way of using "when" for describing a line graph.

> It kept falling until June when it reached the lowest point of -3%.

I want to say that after it stopped decreasing(in June), it was at its lowest point of 3%.

Comment: It's fine (except that almost *every* competent writer would include a comma after ***June*** and perhaps ***falling***). What makes you think it might not be? Note that it's easy to rephrase so you don't need ***when*** at all: *It kept falling until it reached the lowest point of -3% **in June.***

Comment: @KateBunting: It just depends on how you "hear" the text being spoken by your "inner voice". But if I think I'll have a pause / disconnect after just the first three words, I might use a dash rather than a comma: *It kept falling until June - when it reached the [**its?**] lowest point of -3%.*

Comment: Yes, it's right. Most would probably add a comma, though it's not wrong to leave it out (just be sure you're making an intentional choice one way or another). Verbosely, "when" means: "It kept falling until June and in June it stopped when it reached its lowest point of -3%."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**kept falling until June** conveys the meaning "stopped falling in June".  The *when*-clause supplies additional info about the precise level it had fallen to, and doesn't alter or contradict the meaning in your matrix clause.

P.S.  "until June" is not a precise phrase as it is used in everyday speech. If you say, "I'm staying in London until June", it doesn't necessarily mean you're departing on April 30th. You might leave in the first week of June. So the phrase is not guaranteed to mean that the last day of the falling trend was April 30th and that effective June 1st the leveling off occurred.